# Table not loading on power bi desktop

Tags: powerbi

I am getting the following error when i am trying to load a table from hive in power bi desktop.

"**OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] ERROR [HY000] [Hortonworks][Hardy] (35) Error from server: error code: '0' error message: 'Invalid OperationHandle: OperationHandle [opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT, getHandleIdentifier()=e3ffaec5-d446-4a22-adc5-a859d2abfd2a]**"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was got this error until ago.

1. Because my systems have -Power BI and Windows Server- different formats. I could fix it going to Control Panel > Region > Formats > English
   (United States)
2. Other case you can check column types. If you are doing type
   conversion, you should check the data content or Dax function.